# How to convert multiple java files into xml files using srcml?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to convert my java files to xml using srcml (https://www.srcml.org/tutorials/creating-srcml.html)
it gives a command 
srcml filename.java -o somefilename.xml , 
i want to know how can i convert multiple java files seperated by name and generate multiple xml files . for example :
srcml a.java b.java c.java -o a.xml b.xml c.xml.
i am unable to find any such option in srcml

This is for srcml , i have tried for one file at a time it works , but if i loop it for several files , it takes more time . can we run 10 java files in a single command.

```
srcml filename.java -o somefilename.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you refer to (https://www.srcml.org/tutorials/creating-srcml.html) states:

> The same commands apply for project directories, archives, and compressed files.

And gives the following example:

```
srcml --verbose narq.tar.gz -o narq.tar.gz.xml
```

This creates a single output file containing all the source code.

It doesn't seem that `srcml` can create more than one output file in a single pass.